# Regex for one, two, three etc using Node.js

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I am working on regex and facing one problem.  I am not able to finding one, two, three, four etc.  in string using regex in node.js.

Example:  String contains some time Chapter 1 or Chapter one.  I can find 1 but not one.

```
 Chapter one
 Chapter two
 Chapter three
 Chapter four
 .....
```

How to find number in words?

Can any one assist me?

Comment: `/Chapter (?:one|two|three|four|...)\b/`

Comment: What is the maximum number of chapter? Also please show us your regexp so far (even if it does not work)

Comment: it is dynamic.  depends on pages in book.

Comment: I understand, but you need a limit because you basically need to handle the english words yourself

Comment: Ok...   i set limit 600 pages(six hundred)....

Comment: I'll try to find a generic solution to handle large numbers as well (over a thousand) without having to write all of them down :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
str = 'Chapter one';
str.match(/Chapter\s{1}(\w+)/);
// or
str.match(/Chapter (\w+)/);
// or, for: thirty three etc
str.match(/Chapter\s{1}(\w+(\s{1}\w+)?)/);
```

Will return `["Chapter one", "one"]`.

Pattern description:

```
/Chapter\s{1}(\w+)/
Chapter # will match only Chapter (case sensitive)
\s{1}   # one space (you can also use <space>)
(\w+)   # letter, at least one. You can refer to it as 1 element in returned array
```

Comment: how to find twenty two, thirty three etc.  The above pattern get one string after chapter.... If i have two string?

Comment: `str.match(/Chapter\s{1}(\w+(\s{1}\w+)?)/);`. But it will not much hundred twenty two... is it good enough for you?

Comment: What is the purpose of the `{1}`?

Comment: It mean exactly one space. `\s` - white space, `{1}` - exactly 1 character. Is it answer for your question?

Comment: This is old but @cn007b `\s` on it's own is the same as `\s{1}`, you don't need the quantifier if there is only one character you're looking for